# «Аннын» — возможно ли такое притяжательное прилагательное?

Tags: орфография, словообразование, прилагательные

Допустима ли такая форма притяжательного прилагательного — **Аннын**?

Answer (score 2):

*Аннын?* Нет, это совершенно невозможно.

Аня — [Анин](http://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&spd=&text=lexgramm&mode=main&sort=i_grtagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&parent1=0&level1=0&lex1=%D0%90%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BD&gramm1=&sem1=&sem-mod1=sem&sem-mod1=sem2&flags1=&m1=&parent2=0&level2=0&min2=1&max2=1&lex2=&gramm2=&sem2=&sem-mod2=sem&sem-mod2=sem2&flags2=&m2=); Анна — [Аннин](http://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&spd=&text=lexgramm&mode=main&sort=i_grtagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&parent1=0&level1=0&lex1=%D0%90%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BD&gramm1=&sem1=&sem-mod1=sem&sem-mod1=sem2&flags1=&m1=&parent2=0&level2=0&min2=1&max2=1&lex2=&gramm2=&sem2=&sem-mod2=sem&sem-mod2=sem2&flags2=&m2=).

Суффикс **-ын** в притяжательных прилагательных возможен только после **ц**:
львица — львицын; птица — птицын; сестрица — сестрицын; царица — царицын; ящерица — ящерицын; куница — куницын; падчерица — [падчерицын](https://lopatin.academic.ru/92047/%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B%D0%BD).

[Гласные после ***ц***](http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=38)
[Притяжательные прилагательные](https://russkiiyazyk.ru/chasti-rechi/prilagatelnoe/pritiazhatelnye-prilagatelnye.html)